# $X$ is a metric space and $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$ such that $\partial B\subseteq A\subseteq B$. Show that $\partial B\subseteq\partial A$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the following proof of the statement

> $X$ is a metric space and $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$ such that $\partial B\subseteq A\subseteq B$. Then $\partial B\subseteq\partial A$.

correct?

*Proof*: Let $x\in\partial B$. Then $\operatorname{dist}(x,B)=\operatorname{dist}(x,B^c)=0$. Since $\partial B \subseteq A$, we have $\operatorname{dist}(x,A)\leq \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial B)$. But $x\in \partial B$ and so $\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial B)=0$. Thus $\operatorname{dist}(x,A) = 0$ because $\operatorname{dist}$ is non-negative.

From $A\subseteq B$, we have $B^c\subseteq A^c$ and so $\operatorname{dist}(x,A^c)\leq \operatorname{dist}(x,B^c)$. Since $x\in\partial B$, $\operatorname{dist}(x,B^c)=0$ and so $\operatorname{dist}(x,A^c)\leq 0$ which implies $\operatorname{dist}(x,A^c)=0$.

Since $\operatorname{dist}(x,A)=\operatorname{dist}(x,A^c)=0$, we have $x\in \partial A$ and so $\partial B\subseteq\partial A$.

Comment: I've not yet encountered closed sets at this point of the textbook I'm following.

Comment: Looks ok to me. I think it should even be true that $\partial A=\partial B$

Comment: @FShrike - $A$ can also have boundary interior to $B$, for example $B$ being the closed unit disk, and $A$ being the closed annulus with outer radius $1$ and inner radius $\frac 12$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah, thanks for catching that